# Understanding the flow in Gradle project

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gradle, java-8, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am purely from the Maven background, I haven't used the Gradle build so far.

***Completed :***

1. I am able to successfully build this project https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/anomaly-detection using the `./gradlew build`
2. As per the documentation in the project, It is mentioned that `./gradlew :run` command will launch a single node elastic search cluster with the two plugins installed. I tried and I am able to get both the plugins installed like below

   http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/plugins?v&s=component&h=name,component,version,description

[image: name component version description integTest-0 opendistro-anomaly-detection 1.10.0.0 Amazon opendistro elasticsearch anomaly detector plugin integTest-0 opendistro-job-scheduler 1.10.0.0-SNAPSHOT Open Distro for Elasticsearch job schduler plugin]

***Question*** :

Now I am trying to understand this opensource code,

1. What is the purpose of these four tags in build.gradle (https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/anomaly-detection)  : buildscript, plugins, repositories, ext
2. when I look at the `build.gradle`, It seems that the following package is called for building,

   allprojects {
   group = 'com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch'

   ```
    plugins.withId('java') {
        sourceCompatibility = targetCompatibility = "1.8"
    }
   ```

   }

But where is the main method/trigger point for this code (https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/anomaly-detection) ? Could someone look at this github project and let me know the starting point of the code so that I will debug and get the remaining context please!!

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the Gradle questions, I guess they can be answered easily:

1. What is the purpose of these four tags:

   - `buildscript`: This block allows to make settings that are applied *BEFORE* the rest of the build script is loaded. For example, this can be useful to add plugins to the classpath. But that usecase is outdated and the use of the `plugins` block is recommended. ([Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies))
   - `plugins`: With this block you add plugins to the Gradle project. `id 'java'` is typical for Java projects. The plugins are either shipped with Gradle or will be retrieved from remote repositories. This can be configured in the setting.gradle file if required. ([Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html))
   - `repositories`: In order to resolve artifacts from remote repositories (and push to them) you'll have to define these repos. A popular choice is `mavenCentral()` and `jcenter()`, but you can also define your own repos. For corporate use behind firewall we do that a lot. ([Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html))
   - `ext`: This is an extension to the Gradle project that allows you to define additional properties for use throughout the build script. Once defined, you can access them without the `ext.` prefix. ([Documenation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html))
2. `allprojects` iterates over the root project and all subprojects and applies the closure to each project. In this case the group is set to the given string and a command is stored that is executed when Java plugin is applied to that project and sets Java input and output to version 1.8.

As for the main method: I guess you'll have to search the project for a main method. Alternatively, it could be the framework that starts your application. In that case there must be some kind of hook (Overwritten class/implemented interface, Annotation?) for the Framework to start your actual application. You'll have to check that in the framework documentation. Quick start guides could be a great place to start looking.

Comment: Thanks for the response what is the use of this command in the build.gradle : apply plugin: 'elasticsearch.esplugin' ? and I see the esplugin with closure

Comment: With that command the elasticsearch plugin is applied to your project. Most likely this is providing the run task, which you are using. The build script is actually a bit confusing because they are mixing the old and new ways of applying plugins (new: `plugins{...}`, old: `apply plugin: ...`).
The `esplugin` closure allows to configure the plugin. Every plugin can register an extension with an arbitrary name for settings, and this is the one of the esplugin.